# Configure Jetty to scan WEB-INF/classes for web-fragment.xml

Tags: jetty

Is there a way to configure Jetty to scan WEB-INF/classes for web-fragment.xml files?
That configuration is required to run/debug Eclipse Web Module project.
Building JAR file is an expensive operation.

Comment: Need more information.  What version of Jetty? What version of the servlet spec?  How are you starting Jetty? (distro, embedded, maven-plugin, eclipse-plugin) be specific.

Comment: Jetty 8. Servlet API 3.0. Eclipse plugin.